# Embedding a Web page in a C# Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, embedding

I want to create a simple C# Window which displays the contents of a webpage. Is this possible ?

Eg. (what I am trying to do is)

csharp.window.loadUrl("http://www.google.com")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do this in a WebBrowser control. And use Navigate(string url) method to browse to a website. have a look Here for Details

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8ys666.aspx

and here is the details for the WebBrowser Class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to take a look at the Windows Forms [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control, or the [WPF equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, there is also a quite usable control to embed firefox instead of MS Explorer:

[GeckoFX](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/)

Answer (score 2):

Create a form with a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control. You can use its methods to navigate to a page or manipulate the document as you see fit.