# c# how to add a web browser to ToolStripMenuItem_Click and have it open on a new tab

Tags: c#

So, I need to open a manual in a separate browser window on my form app by ToolStripMenuItem_Click. I have no idea where to start as I am in the beginning of my studies. Thanks in advance

Comment: Search **How to create a process with c#** and you'll find out there's a lot to be read. Meaning, do some research first then come here.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for the quick response though. I'll try not to ask stupid questions in the future.

Comment: FYI here on stack overflow are for after research has been done, asking a question should be seen as a last resort

Comment: Thanks for the comment but dcg already pointed that out. Message received and understood. You might as well take a look before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method already you can just use `process.start`:

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://SomeWebaddress");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Got it working but I forgot to specify that it has to be in a new form window. How would I do that?

Comment: @ Topi You will need to add some extra bits of code Here is a page that should help you [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744184/embedding-a-web-page-in-a-c-sharp-window)