# Playing .swf file in 2021?

Tags: c#, flash

How would I go about playing a .swf file in 2021 with C#? "Shockwave flash object" is not available as a choice for me in Visual Studio 2019. Is there any other way?

Comment: Have you tried an older IDE? Maybe a past version of SharpDevelop? I remember using SWF with the Shockwave flash object (I can't remember if had to copy over the **.ocx** or the **.dll** file but they are both found in the Flash Player download from Adobe).

Comment: @VC.One I downloaded SharpDevelop but can't find anything like that. Is there any additional guidance you may be able to provide?

Comment: Sorry you didn't get a solution on the bounty. I'll download SharpDevelop for this here laptop and then let you know how to get Flash working in C# code, if successful. I last used Flash before the Adobe shutdown so I don't know what complications to expect. I'll reply within 24 hrs anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: No, but there is a possible workaround if you are really obsessed with your intent

The Shockwave flash object (Flash*.ocx) is an [Activex Component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) and was part of Adobe Flash Player Plugin, [officially removed from Windows in KB4577586](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4577586-update-for-the-removal-of-adobe-flash-player-october-27-2020-931521b9-075a-ce54-b9af-ff3d5da047d5) in 2020. It was not part of Visual Studio itself.

Refer to
[Adobe Flash Player EOL General Information Page](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html) and
[Microsoft Announcement: Update on Adobe Flash Player End of Support](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/04/update-adobe-flash-end-support/)

The only way to use it is finding a way to manually restore it i.e. installing an old version, as suggested [by this detailed article](https://www.howtogeek.com/707830/how-to-use-adobe-flash-in-2021-and-beyond/). So you could try to reinstall Flash 32.0.0.371 using [this archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20200618035158/https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_32.0.0.371_archive.zip) in your current Windows environment but honestly I don't know how the OS will behave. Once installed, you would be able to see "Shockwave flash object" back in components list of any Visual Studio version.

Comment: Alright, I understand. I don't think it's worth all the effort then, thanks for aiding in this!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Ruffle (https://ruffle.rs/), which is a Flash emulator that can run in a browser using WebAssembly. Then, you could embed the "website" into your application by some web view API (not sure what because I'm not really familiar with C#, but maybe something like CEF ([here](https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef) or [one of the C# bindings](https://cefsharp.github.io/)) or some [Microsoft web thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744184/embedding-a-web-page-in-a-c-sharp-window)).

Comment: Sadly, ruffle does not fully support ActionScript 3 which this Flash file uses.